# If $n-m$ and $n$ are coprime, does that mean that $n$ and $m$ are coprime?

Tags: number-theory

If the difference $x$ between $n$ and $m$ is coprime with $n$, does that mean that $(n, m)$ and $(x, m)$ are also coprime pairs?

Comment: Hint:  if $d\,|\,m$ and $d\,|\,n$ then $d\,|\,n-m$.

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ and $m$ are not coprime, then they have a common divisor $d$ other than $1$. Since $d\mid n$ and $d\mid m$, we have $d\mid n-m$, and thus $n$ and $n-m$ are not coprime. The result follows by contraposition.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,b+ka)$ for integers$a,b,k$. So $gcd(n,n-m)=gcd(n,?)$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that for any two integers $x, y, \gcd(x, y) = \min \{ ax+by \in \Bbb Z^+~ \vert ~ a, b \in \Bbb Z \}$.  So if $\gcd(n-m, n)=1$, then $\exists a, b \in \Bbb Z$ with $1=a(n-m)+bn=(a+b)n-am \Rightarrow \gcd(n, m)=1$.  Similarly, $\gcd(n,m) = 1 \Rightarrow \exists a, b \in \Bbb Z \text{ such that } 1=an+bm =a(n-m)+(a+b)m \Rightarrow \gcd(n-m, m)=1.$